# Project-Open Dont notify

Tags: postfix-mta, openacs, project-open

I am using rhel 7 , and i 'm using the open-source Called "Project-open" : http://www.project-open.com/en/ .

I already configured my postfix environment, I can send message without problem through the command line:

```
echo "This is a test." | mail -s "test message" thiago.emanoel@grape.com
```

But when I try to send an email through project-open, I get nothing.
My acs-mail-lite is configured like this:

```
BounceDomain: grape.com
BounceScanQueue: 120
EnvelopePrefix: bounce
MaxBouncecounte: 10
MaxDaystoBounce: 2
MaxnotificationCount: 4
MMencodebin: usr / bin / mmencode
Notification Interval: 7
NotificationSend: thiago.emanoel@grape.com
send_immediately: 0
Emaildeliverymode: default
SMTPHost: smtp.grape.com
SMTTPPassword: "mypass"
SMTPport: 25
SMTTP Timeout: 60
SMTPUser: thiago.emanoel@grape.com
```

I did all the tests in the FAQ, and I did not find any emails stuck in the queue or similar.

Answer (score 2):

The default configuration of ]project-open[ is to send emails to the SMTP server at localhost. So there is no need to modify acs-mail-lite or anything, but just to install Postfix locally.